# Django 2.x Как после исполнения CreateView вернуться на страницу с которой произошел вызов?

Tags: django, form, view

**ЗАДАЧА:**
*Существует задача(Task). В рамках задачи исполнители ведут переписку (Message).
Иерархия: Задача -> Много сообщений. 
Как после добавления нового сообщения "на лету" вернуться в тело задачи?*

**URLS.py**

```
...
path(
    'message/<uuid:id>/',
    views.MessageCreate.as_view(),
    name='add_message'
),
...
```

**MODEL:**

```
class Message(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Account,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        verbose_name='message author',
        related_name='messages'
    )

    task = models.ForeignKey(
        Task,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='messages'

    )
    text = models.TextField(
        max_length=1000
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('projects:message_detail',
                       args=[
                           self.id
                       ])

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} about {}'.format(self.message_author.get_full_name, self.task.name)
```

**VIEW:**

```
    class MessageCreate(CreateView):
        model = Message
        form_class = MessageForm
        template_name = 'projects/forms/message_cu_form.html'
        success_url = '/'
```

**FORM:**

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = [
            'author',
            'text',
            'task',
        ]
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="{% url 'projects:add_message' task.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Write message</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MessageCreate(CreateView):
    model = Message
    fields = ['author', 'text', 'task']
    template_name = 'projects/forms/message_cu_form.html'

    get_success_url(self):
        return redirect(self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

Или добавить в форму поле `next`, содержащее текущий URL и возвращаться на него, а не на реферер.